# Selectable TreeView in Visual C#

Tags: c#, treeview

Are there any good tutorials out there to develop a selectable TreeView in Visual Studios?
What I am searching for is for something that would display my drives in a tree view and have a checkbox next to each drive, folder and file. This will be used in a replication program. Thanks a million.

Comment: I am looking to create something like RadTreeView

http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/treeview.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you've got the `CheckBoxes` property and there are some sample code for how to use it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.checkboxes.aspx).
This is assuming that you're doing WinForms.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/vbnettristatechkbox.aspx?msg=2752538)'s an article about making the checkboxes tristate and this article contains a screenshot so you can see what it would look like.